# Axios get method vue can reach json data but not its properties

Tags: php, json, vue.js, axios

I want to get data from my database in a vue application. The request is being made with axios. I get the data as a whole object but as soon as I try to reach a propertie the application response that it is undefined. My guess is, that the data is not really converted to JSON format and therefore it can not reach the properties. I already tried JSON.parse() but it does not work.

[I console logged the the data access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1jGG.jpg)
The first console output is the whole object, the second output should be a specific propertie

**Index.html** (where the axios call is made)

```
    methods: {
    getAllBooks(){
        axios.get("url").then(
            function(response) {
                if(response.data.error) {
                    app.errorMsg = JSON.parse(response.data.message);
                } else{
                    app.buecher = response.data;
                    console.log(typeof app.buecher);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(app.buecher)); //if I remove stringify here it logs [object object]
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(app.buecher.ProduktID));
```

**process.php**

```
$response = array();

while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_erg))   
{
    $response[] = $zeile;

}

echo json_encode($response); // as far as I understood $response is JSON from that moment on
mysqli_free_result( $db_erg );
exit;
}

?>
```

Does anyone see the problem here?

Comment: what does your first console.log print?

Comment: It prints object

Comment: what object? can you comment all that it prints?

Comment: it really just prints object nothing more